Missing the first jummah but got to go back to work before 2nd jummah
Assalamu alaikum, I miss the first jummah prayer due to the daylight savings time change. And was late to the first jummah and they had finished praying. I proceeded to pray dhuhr and repented for missing jummah. the masjid does a second jummah however I have to get back to work. What would be the best way to pray? Do I make dhuhr and repent or wait for the 2nd jummah?

Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and the SE model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help]. Please note that I found a fatwa saying that it is not permissible to hold two Jumu'ah prayers in a mosque.
